# Changing TERM variable and color output

Tags: linux, bash

I've set the TERM environment variable like so

```
export TERM=linux-m
```

to switch to non-color term. Now when i issue `ls -l` i indeed got no color output, but when i use for e.g: `grep --color abc 1.txt` it still returns colored output? Why doeas setting the variable affects `ls` command and not `grep`?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly tell `ls` to color its output?

Comment: Yes when i use `ls --color=always` i also get no colors with `ls`. BTW why does it returns colors when I've set monochrome terminal?

Comment: I get color even with `ls --color=always` or `ls --color=auto`

Comment: @Seth Can you just answer my last question?

Comment: @Ringger81 no, I'm not certain why it does either. It was just something to try. if it did work with `always` it might've been that it's "enforcing" the monochrome ... well as it is, it apparently isn't. It's likely outputting the ANSI escape codes for colors. That would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

from `ls` man page:

> With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only  when  standard output is connected to a terminal.

Consequently, if `--color` is set to :

- `always` : ls emits color even the output is redirected to a file ;
- `auto` : ls emits color's code if the output is a terminal, eg. it is not redirected to a file or a pipe, even if terminal has no coloring, as it is not explicitly said that it depends on the terminal capabilities.

Considering grep, I assume that the behavior is the same (try `grep --color=auto... | less` and `grep --color=always ... | less` and you will see the results)

Comment: Ok but my question was how can grep return colored results if the terminal is indeed monochrome (linux-m)?

Comment: oh sorry I didnt meant that. If the underlying terminal emulator (very old xterm, ...) really does not have color capabilities, there is no mean to have color with grep. If the underlying terminal emulator has capabilities, but the `TERM` environment variable is set to a monochrome terminal, you can use `grep --color=always` like with `ls`.

Comment: Yes, but i get colors even with `ls --color=auto -l` and just `ls -l`.

Comment: This is the normal behavior as `--color=always`  is the default behavior of `ls` (see man page). And like I I already said, `ls --color=auto` includes color unless you redirect output to file or pipe.
Considering `grep` the man page does not explicitly provides the default behavior. But as the order of color values are `never, always, auto`, I guess the default behavior is `never`. Moreover you can do : `grep --color=auto` and you will see the same behavior than `ls --color=auto`. Consequently the behavior of `--color` of `ls` and `grep` is the same. The main difference is the default value.

Comment: You said before 'If the underlying terminal emulator has capabilities, but the TERM environment variable is set to a monochrome terminal, you can use grep --color=always like with ls'. Does it mean that the TERM var has no effect at all?

Comment: Yes, that what we get from an empirical approach : `ls` and `grep` does not seem to look at that variable and only rely on the `--color` option and its default value. Maybe this is due because now, most of terminal have at least 8bits color capabilities