# Changing terminal type and colors

Tags: linux

I've set the `TERM` variable value to `linux-m` to have a monochrome terminal. What's peculiar it doesn't changed anything - when i issue `ls -l` or `grep --color` i still get colorized results. Why does it returns colors if the terminal is no-color?

For previous information on this see [Changing TERM variable and color output](https://superuser.com/questions/1289214/changing-term-variable-and-color-output). It's related but has another focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each command (program) has its own options and they override common options of terminal at all.

1. **To have monochrome prompt:** open your `~/.bashrc` file. Find strings begins from `PS1=`, `PS2=`, `PS3=`, `PS4=` and comment them (place `#` at the beginning).
2. **To have monochrome `ls` output:** find file `~/.dircolors` and rename it to `~/.dircolors_old`.
3. **To have monochrome `grep` output:** `grep` takes its colors from environment variable `GREP_COLORS` (deprecated GREP_COLOR). It might be set in `~/.bashrc`. You should comment it too.